# How to solve Boolean Expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

im struggling with this Boolean expression.

If anyone could help me solve it that would be great, I've been struggling with this for over a week now and would really like someones help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjLwy.jpg

Comment: the image does not open on my computer

Comment: sorry, now try it should work.

Comment: same problem, but it could be a domain restriction on my side. Want to rewrite this in MathJax?

Comment: Over a week? That's dedication, kudos to you!  But yes, after some point you need to realize you could use some help.  Now, did you generate any thoughts or attempts in that week+'s worth of effort and thinking?

Comment: Well the result im only getting is that the output is ABCD, but i know that isn't right i'm just stuck and need a answer please.

Comment: Is this for a class? If so, I would suggest you talk to your professor or TA. If the best you can do after a week's struggle is ABCD, then an answer is the last thing you need; you first need some elementary instruction and understanding in how these circuits work. Sorry to be harsh but it needs to be said.

Comment: It's fine man i understand thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

$X=A\wedge (B\vee \neg C) \wedge (C \vee D)$

$X=A\wedge (C \implies B) \wedge (C \vee D)$

$X=A\wedge (D \vee B)$

$\wedge$ is and

$\vee$ is or

$\neg$ is not

Comment: Im not not sure if this is right because in msot of the exampels that were taught to us in lectures didnt involve the ^ -> symbols. If you could try make it a bit more specific for me that would be great buddy!

Comment: can you tell me exactly what part is problematic?

Comment: A.(B+C ̅).(C+D) =
(AB+A C ̅).(C+D) =
ABC + ABD + AC ̅C + ACD =
ABC + ABD + AC ̅D = X

is this right?

Comment: Yes but you can continue simplifying at the end you should find $X=A(B+D)$

Comment: I am really sorry I didnt understand you were not understating my notations you should ov told me you were using AB for A and B and A+B for A or B